# Azure Function App remove headers set by a Nest.js App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, nestjs, serverless

Thanks for the time reading this.

I am developing an App using Nest.js framework, running it on Azure App service.

I am using a library which set some headers before sending the response to the client.
When I run my code on local runtime, everything seems working properly.
But, when I use Azure Function App local runtime, headers seems to disappear.

There is a screenshot of the request using local runtime

[image]
As you can see in the “Response Headers” section there some headers set.

And then a screenshot of the same server code running on Azure Function App local runtime

[image]

As you can see in the “Response Headers” section some headers are missing.

**My question is, how do I configure Azure Function App so that it does not remove headers set by my Nest.js App  ?**

I’ve been looking into MS documentation about that, but I did not find anything.

Thank you. for your help

Comment: How are you handling the Http request. Is it possible to show your function code handling the request & response?

Comment: It seems there's an open issue logged for this. Check if the workaround mentioned may help: https://github.com/nestjs/azure-func-http/issues/407#issuecomment-849541060